# Replace part of variable name with value of another variable?

Tags: php, session

I have one huge translation file which includes all variables starting with the language code like `$de_`.

```
$de_anzahl = 'Anzahl';
$en_anzahl = 'Quantity';
$nl_anzahl = 'Aantal';
$tr_anzahl = 'Miktar';
$ru_anzahl = 'Количество';
```

Usage in 5 different php files looks like the following - for each language only the first two letters change to target the desired language like `$nl_`

```
<?php echo $nl_anzahl; ?>
```

Is it possible to change a part of the variable name by replacing the language part with the value of a variable i extract from the session storage. Something like that:

```
<?php $nl_language_code = 'nl'; ?>
<?php echo $<?php echo $nl_language_code; ?>_anzahl; ?>
```

If this is possible i would be able to bulk find and replace the parts and reduce 5 files into one.

Comment: You are better off with defining constant arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `<?php ...` when you're already inside PHP. You can use this:

```
<?php

$de_anzahl = 'Anzahl';
$en_anzahl = 'Quantity';
$nl_anzahl = 'Aantal';
$tr_anzahl = 'Miktar';
$ru_anzahl = 'Количество';

$nl_language_code = 'nl';

echo ${$nl_language_code . '_anzahl'};
```

will output `Aantal`.

The easier way I think would be to use arrays though

Answer (score 0):

you can also use curly brackets like this:

```
$de_anzahl = 'Anzahl';
$en_anzahl = 'Quantity';
$nl_anzahl = 'Aantal';
$tr_anzahl = 'Miktar';
$ru_anzahl = 'Количество';

$lang = 'ru_anzahl';
echo ${$lang};
```